# Adding <br> between small and big letter which has no space between them

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have multiline text, in which sometimes can be found such text: "blabla bla bla blaLia lia lia lia"

Is it posible to find such small and capital letters which are not separated by space and insert `<br />` between them to get text like this: "blabla bla bla bla`<br />`Lia lia lia lia"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you can

Regex:`(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])`

Replace with:`<br />`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. There has to be something to replace.

Comment: @MikeM you have to select the **match-case** option

Comment: I have. Tried it again. It works with _Replace All_, but not _Replace_, strangely. Can anybody else confirm?

Comment: @MikeM hmm...you are right..is it a **bug**..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have notepad++ installed but from memory you can use the regex expression

`([a-z])([A-Z])`

in the replace field you should be able to do `\1<br />\2`

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
$string = 'blabla bla bla blaLia lia lia lia';

$string = preg_replace('/[A-Z]/', '<br>$0', $string);

echo $string;
```